# There is an error changing the Apache root path

Tags: php, laravel, apache, server, webserver

If  i enter my domain ( localhost ) and connect to it, i will see a list of all my projects, but I want to modify it to connect to the path of the specified project the first time I connect.

So I changed the Apache configuration file as shown below but it does not work. Same as before. How do I fix it so that I can access the main screen of the specified project directly?

I am currently working laravel on Windows

```
--  httpd.conf--
DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.21-0/apache2/htdocs/projectname/public"
<Directory "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.21-0/apache2/htdocsc/omanager/public">
```

I am not accustomed to English. Please understand if I made a mistake, and thank you very much for reading my post.

Comment: Use virtual hosting, or you can just include the folder in the URL and then modify the htaccess (rewrite base) etc.   Just don't upload the local htaccess file, and keep your links in a way that allows you to change the domain easily (something you should do anyway if you build in a development environment, without the domain name).  This has more to do with the URL then the Path.

Comment: You misspelled "htdocs"   ... You have "htdocsc"